# Linux: How to delete lines starting at a pattern to another pattern using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I am aware of how to delete certain patterns with the help of sed.

Here is an example:

```
exampleFile

One Two Three Four
Five Six Seven
Eight One Nine Four
```

If I apply the following, all 'One's will be deleted.

```
sed 's/\<One\>//g' exampleFile
```

But what if I wanted to delete everything starting from One until Four? The output I am looking for is:

```
Five Six Seven
Eight
```

I thought about writing the following, but it does not work:

```
sed 's/\<One*Four\>//g' exampleFile
```

(I thought that by putting an *, it should mean delete everything in between and including One and Four)... Is my request even possible in one line?

Thank you!

Comment: *face-palm* Thanks, I feel a little embarrassed now because it was so easy.

Answer (score 2):

In regex, `.` means "any character" and `*` means "any number of the previous element", so you'd do:

```
sed 's/\<One.*Four\>//g' exampleFile
```

You can further add appropriate angle brackets to ensure that the One and Four have to be separate words:

```
sed 's/\<One\>.*\<Four\>//g' exampleFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @that other guy's answer, removing blank line as well

```
sed -e 's/\<One\>.*\<Four\>//g' -e '/^$/d' exampleFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/\<One\>.*\<Four\>/{s/\<Four\>/\n/;s/\<One\>[^\n]*\n//;/^\s*$/d;ba}' file
```

This checks to see if the strings `One` and `Four` occur on the same line and if so replaces the second string with a marker (`\n`) and then removes from the first string to and including the marker. If the remaining line is empty or contains only white space the line is deleted otherwise the process is repeated till the first condition no longer applies.

N.B. This caters for lines where the second string may occur more than once. The method above can be applied to multiple lines however care must be taken to ensure that both strings exist.